# Dungeons and Dragons - Ability scores generation

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, random

I'm trying to create an array variable containing 6 numbers from 3 to 18, generated the way we generate the ability scores for D&D 5th edition.
For those who are not familiar with the game, the concept is to roll 6 die, and add up the 3 highest results, in order to get an ability score between 3 and 18.

My problem is that even tho it is supposed to have a range between 3-18, it sometimes generates a score of 0, and never really seems to go higher than 14...
Also, if I try to do a do/while loop until the result is higher than 17, just to check out if it is possible, I get some scores of 24 and even 34... So actually, what am I doing wrong? I tried a lot of things, and still it doesn't work... if anyone could help me out, I'd be so grateful!

Here is my code for the moment:

```
function generation() {

    var abilities = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
    var i, k, c, n, p;

    //for each ability (there is 6)
    for (c = 0; c <= 5; c++){

        var scores = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
        var nb = [-1,-2,-3] 
        var diffMax = 0;
        var iDiff = 0;
        var diff = 0;

            //roll 6 die
            for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++){

                scores[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);

            }

            //for each die rolled
            for (k = 0; k <= 5; k++){

                //compare to each score slot (there is 3)
                for (n = 0; n <= 2; n++){

                    //determine difference
                    diff = scores[k] - nb[n];

                    //if the difference is higher than the previously determined difference
                    if (diff >= diffMax){

                        //note the difference and the position
                        iDiff = n;
                        diffMax = diff;

                    }

                }

                //replace the lowest score slot by the result if this result is higher than the score slot
                if (diffMax >= 0){

                    nb[iDiff] = scores[k];

                }

            }

            //add up each score slot
            for (p = 0; p <= 2; p++){

                abilities[c] = abilities[c] + nb[p];

            }

    }

    return abilities;

}
```

Comment: I'd say this is the basic "random integer in javascript" question, which is answered by, "function ( min, max ) { return Math.floor ( Math.random () * ( max - min + 1 )) + min; }"

Comment: (You feed in "3, 18"). By the way I've been a fan of D&D since a couple of years before the original Red Box Basic Rules :)

Comment: Yeah, this will do the job for a random number between nb1 and nb2, but this type of generation is not linear, it's way easier to get a number around 10 and way harder to get a 1 or a 18, because of the way it's generated, so going with a simple max/min won't do the trick :/

Comment: Ah, if you're looking for "very advanced random number gen," your question is underpowered. Or, you could generate three random nums between 1, 6 (so use that random num function three times).

Comment: Well, I think I described the way I generate the numbers in the question, which is 6 die rolled, and the 3 best results are added up together :P

Comment: Ok, roll the random num gen 6 times, collect the results in an array, sort the array, reduce to the sum of the first three.

Comment: Ooooh dams I forgot you can sort the Arrays! Thank's! Sorry if this is a newbie mistake, I'm a student at the moment, been into Javascript for a few months only ;)

Comment: Will post an answerl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From prior comments:

```
let rolls = [];
let min = 1;
let max = 6;
let numrolls = 6;

for ( let i = 0; i < numrolls; i++ ) {
   // Probably put this in a util function
   rolls.push ( Math.floor ( Math.random () * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min );
}

rolls = rolls.sort ( ( a, b ) => { return a < b; } );

let result = rolls
    .splice ( 0, 3 )
    .reduce ( ( a, b ) => {  return a + b; } );

console.log ( result );
```

Comment: From there you can probably see how to use different dice, even different kinds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you're after like this:

```js
function sumOfThreeDice() {
    rolls = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].map((x) => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6));
    rolls.sort();
    sum = rolls[5] + rolls[4] + rolls[3];
    return sum;
}
console.log(sumOfThreeDice());
```

We roll 6 dice, then add up the largest 3 by sorting the array. If you want to do this multiple times to fill up an array, you could do:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].map(sumOfThreeDice);    // generates 6 D&D ability scores
```